# Log4j2 GC-Free Async loggers: passing mutable objects

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using log4j version 2.10.0

I am trying to set up gc-free logging with mixed async and sync loggers(so it's configured via xml configuration with some `<AsyncLogger>` tags). The question is: what if I pass a mutable object to async logger? Would it first create a message and then pass it to background or it will create it only in background, meaning that it could log already changed object? Would the behaviour be different if I make all loggers async(via property using `AsyncLoggerContextSelector` instead of `AsyncLogger` xml tag)?

The objects are mutable because I want to reuse them in the future, for example, instead of creating new ones.

I saw this question: [slf4j-log4j converts objects to string before passing to Asynchronus logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43259076/slf4j-log4j-converts-objects-to-string-before-passing-to-asynchronus-logger).
But I believe the gc-free behaviour could be different from just async(As it mentioned in answer on that question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log4j2 will render the message in the application thread before returning from the logging method, to ensure that what is written to the log file is the value at the time that the logger was called.

This works out of the box with all async logging methods (async appender as well as both flavours of async loggers).  With garbage free logging this works similarly, the only difference is the data structures used by Log4j2 internally. The fact that the message is rendered before passing it to the background thread is the same.

There is a system property to render the message in the background thread but I would not recommend this unless you are very confident that the application doesn’t modify the objects that were logged.

Comment: The JavaDoc's for the ```Message``` interface (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message.html) state : "Message objects should not ... be assumed to be safely reusable ... The logging system may provide information to the Message objects and the Messages might be queued for asynchronous delivery. Thus, any modifications to a Message object by an application should by avoided after the Message has been passed...".  Is the documentation incorrect, because it appears to contradict your answer.

Comment: @remko can you please look into the above java doc? is it an obsolete warning? also ```It is safe to asynchronously log mutable objects because most Message implementations built-in to Log4j take a snapshot of the parameters``` is mentioned in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#AllAsync. Can you please explain how parameter snapshots are taken? will it not result in garbage?